# Should InputStreamReader be used with appendCodePoint?

Tags: java, unicode

It is a common pattern in Java to read characters from a file with InputStreamReader and append them to a StringBuilder; the obvious way to do it is like:

```
int c = reader.read();
sb.append((char)c);
```

However, supposing the file (assuming we specified UTF-8 encoding if it makes a difference) were to contain a character (strictly speaking a code point) that doesn't fit in 16 bits. Would the reader return this as a single 32-bit code point instead of a pair of 16-bit chars?

If so, should the last line above actually read like:

```
sb.appendCodePoint(c);
```

Is there a known test case - a sequence of UTF-8 bytes - that would distinguish between the two options?

Comment: It's not that common. Most code reads into buffers or reads lines actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reader returns whatever it can make of the next piece of input, as a single character, as the Javadoc says. The only exception is the EOS indicator, which is -1 as an `int.` There is no basis for your suggestion.

Comment: True. Notice, however that "a single Java character", is actually a UTF-16 codepoint, so if the source cointains  a Unicode character outside the BMP, you will be reading this Unicode character as two Java chars. But: 1) this is not problematic in this scenario 2) this is not related with the underlying encoding (UTF-8 or whatever)